# How to synchronize two datagrids in WPF (.NET Framework)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have two datagrids in my project. One of them is the main grid and the other is filtered version of the main grid. When I run my project, I can get the datas from excel file and successfully perform the filtering operation. The problem is; I have multiple tabs and when I switch between the tabs, my filtered data grid stays the same. I have to click a button to switch new datas. What I want is  changing the filtered grid simultaneously when the main grid changes. I use MVVM structure and binding. My view model is like that:

```
public List<MyEntity> List { get; set; } = new List<MyEntity>(); //For main datagrid
public List<MyEntity> TempList { get; set; } = new List<MyEntity>(); // For filtered datagrid

public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand FilteredListCommand{ get; set; }

public TolType SelectedTolType { get; set; } //Every tab keeps different type excel file. So I control them with enum. TolType is the enum.

public ViewModel()
{
}

private void MainList(object obj)
{
            List.Clear();
            TempList.Clear();

            SelectedTolType = (TolType)obj;
            List = genelManager.GetAll(SelectedTolType);

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List));
}

private void FiteredList(object obj)
{
            if (SelectedTolType == 0) return;
            TempList = List.FindAll(x => x.OkNotOk == false);
            
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TempList));
}
```

And my XAML is like that:

```
<StackPanel>

<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/> 
<DataGrid x:Name="dg2" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/>

<ToggleButton Content="First Tab"
              Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{x:Static local:TolType.Tab1}"/> 
<ToggleButton Content="Second Tab"
              Command="{Binding AddCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static locad:TolType.Tab2}"/>
 
<ToggleButton Content="Filter"
              Command="{Binding FilteredListCommand}">
 
</StackPanel>
```

I tried to change my FilteredListCommand prop but somehow I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to sort, group or filter data for displaying in the view, always use the `ICollectionView` of the original collection to perform such actions. Modifying the collection view will not modify the underlying collection. See [Binding to collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-to-collections) to learn more.

Additionally, use an `ObservableCollection`. If you plan to modify the source collection use `ObservableCollection`. Then `Add` or `Remove` items instead of overwriting the collection instance.

To solve your problem, you must introduce a new collection view that you can bind the filtered `DataGrid` to. Updating the underlying collection will also update the view.

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> List { get; }
public ICollectionView FilteredListView { get; }

public ViewModel()
{
  this.List = new ObservableCollection<MyEntity>();
  this.FilteredListView = new ListCollectionView(this.List);
}

private void UpdateList(object obj)
{
  List.Clear();
  SelectedTolType = (TolType)obj;
  IEnumerable<MyEntity> newItems = genelManager.GetAll(SelectedTolType);

  // Since FilteredListView is a ICollectionView of List,
  // modifying List will also modify FilteredListView.
  foreach (var item in newItems)
  {
    this.List.Add(item);
  }
}

private void FilterList(object obj)
{
  if (SelectedTolType == 0) 
    return;

  this.FilteredListView.Filter = item => !(item as MyEntity).OkNotOk;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" /> 
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredListView}" />
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer and proper way to go.   (You have a small typing error in the last line (item => items).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have fixed the typo. Thanks for improving this answer.